# Как решить проблему с matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Делаю упражнения из книги Эрика Маттеса,импортирую матплотлиб, пишу самый простой график, а мне выбивает что:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\python_work\mpl_squares.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tempfile.py", line 45, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\python_work\random.py", line 1, in <module>
    from random import choice
ImportError: cannot import name 'choice' from partially initialized module 'random' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\python_work\random.py)
```

Устанавливал матплотлиб я как в книге,методом pip

Вот программа:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

squares = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(squares)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Во-первых, из ошибки ясно, что проблема не с матплотлиб. Во-вторых, в приведённом коде нет строчки, которая вызывает эту ошибку. В-третьих, в тексте ошибки указана её причина. В-пятых, даже на этом сайте примерно 100500 ответ по этой ошибке. В-шестых, если ты по каждой ошибке будешь бежать в интернет за помощью, даже не попытавшись решить проблему самостоятельно, то далеко не уедешь

Comment: Да, круто, а причём здесь JavaScript?

Comment: Ребят,я не просил умничать или учить меня как и что делать,я пришел сюда что бы узнать решение своей проблемы,ибо я чайник в программировании.Я впервые на этом сайте,я не понимаю что от меня хочет пайтон в данной ситуации

Comment: Зачем ты назвал свой скрипт random.py ? Переименуй его или удали вообще.